# User is not returned from login and app.currentUser is an empty object - Mongo Realm Sync

Tags: realm

I couldn't find a similar question so I will ask here:
I'm using the Realm library and the react-native SDK to build an app.
I started by running the example app https://github.com/mongodb-university/realm-tutorial-react-native
I can start the app in xcode, login, and register, and even add a task, but every time I try to get the current user that is signed to the app it gives me an empty object.

For example I have tried to log the user (code is taken from the repo mentioned above - Auth Provider):

```
  const signIn = async (email, password) => {
    const creds = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(email, password);
    const newUser = await app.logIn(creds);
    console.log('====', { newUser, creds, app: app.currentUser });

    setUser(newUser);
  };
```

The log I get is: `LOG  ==== {"app": {}, "creds": {}, "newUser": {}}`

As I mentioned the app is WORKING and I can see the users and tasks added OK on the Realm UI app. What am I missing? How can I get the user?
(I would like to save it in a secured storage and in the app state to change the screens depending on the auth state of the user)

Comment: Just for verification, check out the [Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/realm-app/#authentication) section of the docs and ensure the Email/Password entry in the list of authentication providers is set. I would then suggest checking the Logs (in the console) to look at the sequence of what happens when your auth and then log in; there maybe a clue